# Threading wxPython app with background process for multitouch detection

Tags: events, user-interface, wxpython, python-multithreading

So basically I have some code for multitouch detection and I would like to run it as a separate thread which sends custom events to a wxPython GUI upon a multitouch event.

Now I could post the code for the multitouch tracking but to use it you would require a trackpad, the server app and the detection code, so I think it's better to consider a simple example for the sake of the question.

So for example lets assume an event simulator sending an event every 10 seconds:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent
import time

MultiTouchEvent, EVT_MULTITOUCH = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class EventSimulator:

    def __init__(self):
        self.eventdata = 0

    def Start(self):
        self.RunTUIO()

    def RunTUIO(self): 
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
            wx.PostEvent(GUI, MultiTouchEvent(self.eventdata))
            self.eventdata += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    MultiTouchTracker = EventSimulator() 
    MultiTouchTracker.Start()
```

Now I would like to receive these events whenever they occur within a wxPython GUI (something like this):

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
     def __init__(self, title):
         wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(350,200))
         self.Bind(EVT_MULTITOUCH, self.handler)

     def handler(self, event):
         data = event.data, 
         print data

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    window = Frame("My Basic GUI")
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The problem is I cannot workout how to combine these two pieces of code into a working example. As I understand it I need to run the event simulator as a separate thread from within the GUI code. Please can someone explain how to do this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For details on multi-threading in Python see the docs for the `threading` module in the stock Python library.  There is an example of using it in a GUI in the `Threads` module in the wxPython demo, although there are other viable approaches as well.  (Deriving from the Thread class instead of just using one, etc.)  That demo module also shows a convenient way to make a new event class and binder using the `wx.lib.newevent` module.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at several of the docs and also loads of examples but I struggled to get it working. I found they were usually about discussing some operation performed in a second thread when a button is pressed, not a second process running in parallel with the GUI for the complete execution time. But I will have another look!